# How to increase SQLite driver's length limit on index names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Is there an easy way to increase the sqlite3 driver's limit of 62 characters on index names? On my Mac the limit is 64 characters. On a linux environment I need to use, the limit is 62 characters.

Comment: There is no such limit.

Comment: @CL. Really? Rails is complaining it can't create the index because of the name length. I assumed it was a database limitation because the same rails on my Mac was able to create that.

Comment: So this question is actually about a rails migration that tries to …?

Comment: @CL. It's not a migration, it's a rails schema. I don't know if it's a rails issue yet. I assumed this was a sqlite3 issue.

Comment: Sorry, this bug typically appears with a temporary index during migrations. Anyway, this is not an issue with SQLite itself.